# what is the equivalent index.js for the latest @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to run my tests with cypressv10 and with latest @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, but failing at the index.js ..can some one pls help

my index.js:

const cucumber = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor").default;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
on("file:preprocessor", cucumber());

};

Comment: were u able to solve this with the existing index.js file. Please share ur findings.

Answer (score 0):

In cypress 10 the way to specify the plugins by using the file `plugin/index.js` was deprecated.

I had your same issue and was able to resolve it by using the library `@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor`

This is how the `cypress.config.ts` file looks like now.

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import createBundler from "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import createEsbuildPlugin from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild";

async function setupNodeEvents(
  on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
  config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
  await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    createBundler({
      plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
    })
  );

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}


export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    ...
    setupNodeEvents
  }
});
```

Please note that this example is for typescript, [In here](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/tree/0da4d574a16cd46b97a8fa991126e205bb29327e/examples) you can see the official examples including the setup for raw js.